# Window scroll event using @HostListener not working

Tags: angular, typescript, scroll, header, sticky

I have problem making sticky header when scrolling down, in an Angular 4 application. Scroll event can't be detected.

Header is placed in the layout component, and the content I want to be scrolling is placed in routes component. May that be the problem?

This is the code I implemented.

**In layout.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, HostListener, Inject } from '@angular/core';

import { DOCUMENT } from "@angular/platform-browser";

@Component({

  selector: 'app-layout',

  templateUrl: './layout.component.html',

  styleUrls: ['./layout.component.css']
})

export class LayoutComponent implements OnInit {

  public navIsFixed: boolean = false;

  constructor(public router: Router, @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any) { }

  @HostListener('window:scroll', [ ])

    onWindowScroll(){
      const number = window.pageYOffset || 
      document.documentElement.scrollTop || 
      document.body.scrollTop || 0;
      if (number > 50) {
        this.navIsFixed = true;
      } else if (this.navIsFixed && number < 10) {
      this.navIsFixed = false;
      }
    }
}
```

**In layout.component.html**

```
<div [class.fixed]="navIsFixed" class="header">
```

Comment: What if you define it in the top-level component? app.component.ts (i assume your router-outlet is there...)

Comment: <router-outlet></router-outlet> is placed in layout.component.html @Carsten

Comment: did you find a solution? I have the same issue @tolceza

Comment: @natdico please see the answer above, the main component must have the overflow property. Note : don't try to add this property with DevTools, in that case that would not work

Answer (score 8):

I just had the same problem, all what I had to do was to make sure that the component element is actually what is scrolling & that it has a `overflow` property with values `scroll` or `auto`.

Otherwise just this worked:

```
@HostListener('scroll')
  public asd(): void {
  console.log('scrolling');
}
```

Comment: "make sure component  has a overflow property with values scroll or auto" solved my problem

Answer (score 4):

Your layout must be the source of the issue. The scroll event works only when the the component template element can actually scroll.

Make sure the div has overflow property set to scroll. Also, change the div dimensions so the scroll could trigger.

In order to make it work, I would suggest to make it to the directive and set to a div that has 100vh in height and 100vw in width.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[trackScroll]' })
export class TrackScrollDirective {
    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    }

    @HostListener('document:scroll', [])
    onScroll(): void {
         console.log('I am scrolled');
    }
}
```

See this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngtsju?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) that I made.

Comment: @tolceza you should accept this answer as a solution!

Comment: `Your layout must be the source of the issue`. Can you elaborate what this means? If I can't give `height` and `width` as `100vw` how can I track if scroll action is performed on component?

Comment: @rainversion_3, I wasn't clear there for sure. Does the div have overflow:scroll on it? You don't need the full width and height for the scroll to work

Answer (score 3):

This should give you scroll events:

```
@HostListener('scroll', ['$event'])
onScroll(event) {
  ...
}
```

or

```
<div (scroll)="onScroll($event)"
```

Comment: Thanks but it is not even detecting the scroll event.

Comment: Works on Chrome, not on Firefox.

Comment: @Carsten this gives Maximum call stack size exceeded error

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, I added this to "nav.component":

```js
@HostListener('window:scroll', [])
onWindowScroll() {
    console.log(window.scrollY);

    if (window.scrollY > 90) {
        this.isSticky = true;
    } else {
        this.isSticky = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could not make it work with `scroll` but with `wheel`:

```
@HostListener('window:wheel', ['$event'])
onWheel(event: MouseEvent) {
  // do what you want here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was a simple `overflow-x: hidden` placed on the <html> scope. Removing and replacing it right under, on the <body> scope, fixed the problem, while keeping my overflow configuration.

Every component can detect scroll events, regardless of hierarchy. There is no need to worry about parent/child relations.